# How can i disable link styling?

Tags: jquery-mobile

How can I completely disable jquery mobile styling for certain container?

I am using `data-enhance="false"` for container along with javascript code:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
  $.mobile.ignoreContentEnabled = true;
});
```

Yet some jquery mobile styling remains, for example link color:

```
.ui-page-theme-a a{
color: #38C;
font-weight: 700;}
```

I had to overwrite these css rules manually, it is pretty cumbersome.

Comment: Manually. You can actually only [*"theme"*](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0rc2/docs/api/themes.html) your mobile app. You have to override styles at your own in a separate CSS. Use web inspector tool to find the elements you want to override styles for.

Comment: Yet using data-enhance=false disables some styling.

Answer (score 0):

if you have less CSS to overwrite, then overwriting same classes in our css with !important is best way.

If you are overwriting many classes then don't include jQuery mobile theme CSS just use jQuery mobile structure CSS as its requires for some functionalities such as transition and all.

One more option modify Jquery theme CSS as requires means remove unwanted class as jquery mobile is open source you are good on this.